# plot value error despite same shape of X and Y

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on ML project where I am trying to plot the `roc_curve` using the below code

```
plot_roc_curve(rfc,ord_train_t,y_train)
```

Here `rfc` is my model, `ord_train_t` is my input train data and `y_train` is the labels for training data. The shape of input and output is given below

[image]   [image]

But I am not sure from where the below error is caused (my input and output don't have 200 rows anywhere)

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (732, 15)
```

The full error is given below

```
----> 1 plot_roc_curve(rfc,ord_train_t,y_train)

C:\Users\abcd~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4180/1232546388.py in plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, label)
      6     plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
      7     plt.title('ROC Curve')
----> 8     plt.plot(fpr, tpr, linewidth=2, label=label)
      9     plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
     10     plt.axis([-0.005, 1, 0, 1.005])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)    3017 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)    3018 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 3019     return gca().plot(    3020         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,    3021         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)    1603         """    1604     kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1605         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]    1606         for line in lines:    1607             self.add_line(line)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in
__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    313                 this += args[0],
    314                 args = args[1:]
--> 315             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    316 
    317     def get_next_color(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in
_plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    499 
    500         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 501             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    502                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    503         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (200,) and (732, 15)
```

Comment: Please do not use the comment space for adding such info - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you passed the model to `plt.plot` in `plot_roc_curve` function.

```py
def plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, label):
    ...
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, linewidth=2, label=label)
    ...
```

Comment: how it should be done? I see that in this tutorial, they have done the same - https://www.yourdatateacher.com/2021/06/14/are-you-still-using-0-5-as-a-threshold/

Comment: It is correctly passed. You can refer the documentation here - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html

Comment: In the tutorial, they used `sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve` while you defined your own `plot_roc_curve` function whose first argument is 'fpr'. Re-import with `from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve`.

Comment: No, I am using the same sklearn metrics plot_roc_curve function. I dont have my own. I just followed the tutorial as it is

Comment: In the error message above, "C:\Users\abcd~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4180/1232546388.py in plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, label)" tells that the function on where error occurred is what you'd defined in your iPython kernel.

Comment: If you correctly imported the function, you'll get an error message of path "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_plot/roc_curve.py in plot_roc_curve(estimator, X, y, sample_weight, drop_intermediate, response_method, name, ax, pos_label, **kwargs)".

Comment: I had to restart the kernel and it worked for some reason